# ActionScript 3 KeyboardEvent not firing

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, flashdevelop

I'm new to ActionScript development and am using the FlashDevelop IDE. I've been playing around with some really simplistic things and have come across a problem I can't seem to solve.

My application compiles and runs, and a function that watches click events fires perfectly and I can see the event in the console when I pass it to trace(), yet the same code watching for KeyboardEvent fails to fire at all.

Here's my code:

```
package GameTesting
{

    import flash.display.Bitmap;
    import flash.display.BitmapData;
    import flash.display.Sprite;

    import flash.events.Event;
    import flash.events.MouseEvent;
    import flash.events.KeyboardEvent;

    [Frame(factoryClass="GameTesting.Preloader")]
    public class Main extends Sprite
    {

        public function Main():void
        {
            if (stage) {
                init();
            } else {
                addEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, init);
            }
        }

        private function init(e:Event = null):void
        {
            removeEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE,init);

            addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, onClickEvent);
            addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, onKeyDownEvent);
        }

        private function onKeyDownEvent(e:KeyboardEvent):void
        {
            trace(e);
        }

        private function onClickEvent(e:MouseEvent):void
        {
            trace(e);
        }

    }

}
```

The MouseEvent trace() fires every time as expected, but KeyboardEvent never fires, no matter what key I press. Any ideas?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to add the listeners to the stage:

```
private function init(e:Event = null):void
{
    removeEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE,init);

    stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, onClickEvent);
    stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, onKeyDownEvent);
}
```

Comment: I had that originally, and it didn't work. Since I didn't really know what the stage object was, I took it out and since the CLICK event continued to work, I assumed it was similar to the top-level window object in the browsers. Either way, even with stage.addEventListener() it still isn't working, though oddly enough the CLICK event continues to function. I'm so confused. :/

Comment: Well, I don't know what happened, but when I compiled my code today, it worked. Even though I swear to God that I've changed nothing. Maybe FlashDevelop is a buggy IDE? Who knows. Either way, now that it does work, I was able to verify that calling addEventListener on the stage object is required for the KeyboardEvents, though not for the MouseEvents. Don't know why, but good to know anyway. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 3):

You may need to be sure the movieclip listening for the event has focus.  If you have some sort of menu or start screen for your game that you click a button on to start, that movieclip can retain focus even if it has been removed from stage.

Here's a good article explaining this in further detail:
[Keyboard events on stage are not working...?](http://www.actionscript.org/resources/articles/900/1/Keyboard-events-on-stage-are-not-working-why/Page1.html)

Answer (score 1):

If you are in the Flash IDE (for CS4 at least) you will also need to disable the keyboard shortcuts when you debug (Ctrl+Shift+Enter) or test (Ctrl+Enter) the fla.

In the movie window, select 'Control'->'Disable Keyboard Shortcuts'.
This will stop the Flash IDE recieving the keyboard input, and allow the debug/test window to instead.